# What kind of ODE is this, and what method do I use to solve it?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have a function $y(x)$ satisfying $ay'' + by' + cy = 0$. I also have nonlinear functions $f(y)=y^2+(y')^2$ and $g(y)=ky^2$. Suppose $$f'(x) + f(x) = g(x).$$ What kind of ODE is this, and what method do I use to solve it?

If it were $f'(y) + f(y) = g(y)$, then I would feel comfortable treating this as a linear inhomogeneous ODE and using variation of parameters, since the equation is a sum of functions of $y$ with coefficients that are functions of $y$. But with $f'(x) + f(x) = ky^2$, we have a sum of functions of both $x$ and $y$, and it doesn't seem appropriate to treat $y$ as a constant in $x$.

How should I approach this?

---

This is the problem I'm trying to solve:

Let $y(t)$ be a solution of the ODE $$ay'' + by' + cy = 0.$$ We define

$$P(t) = \frac c2 y^2$$ $$E(t) = \frac a2 (y')^2 + \frac c2 y^2 = \frac a2 (y')^2 + P(t)$$ Suppose that $E$ satisfies $$E'(t) + E(t) = P(t).$$ I wish to find the general solution for $E$.

Comment: This does not make much sense. (It should probably be $...+cy=0$.) Is the $f$ a function of the value of the function $y$, which does not work, or is it a functional, transforming any input function into the function on the right side? Then the last equation would be this functional equation applied to the identity function $x$. But in what sense would one have to take the derivative of the functional? As a variational derivative? Another slight association is the method of Lyapunov functions, but that also does not fit well.

Comment: @LutzLehmann $f$ is a function of the value of $y$; why won't it work?

Comment: Because $y'$ is usually completely independent of $y$. You can do something like $f(y,y')=y^2+y'^2$, or you can do $f\{y\}=[x\mapsto y(x)^2+y'(x)^2]$, but what you wrote is just undefined. If you can, add a little more context to the question text.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I've added more context; I hope the question is more clear now.

Comment: Ok, that makes a little more sense, in direction Lyapunov. You can compute $$\frac{d}{dt}E(t)=y'(ay''+cy)=-by'^2=-\frac{2b}a(E(t)-P(t)),$$ which is now close to your equation for $E$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+b\frac{dy}{dt}+cy=0$$
Solving this linear second order ODE with constant coefficients is wellknown.
$$y(t)=c_1e^{r_1t}+c_2e^{r_2t}\qquad
\begin{cases}
r_1=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \\
r_2=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
\end{cases}$$
$\frac{dy}{dt}=c_1r_1e^{r_1t}+c_2r_2e^{r_2t}$
$$P(t)=\frac{c}{2}\left( c_1e^{r_1t}+c_2e^{r_2t}\right)^2$$
$$\boxed{E(t)=\frac{a}{2}\left(c_1r_1e^{r_1t}+c_2r_2e^{r_2t} \right)^2 + \frac{c}{2}\left( c_1e^{r_1t}+c_2e^{r_2t}\right)^2}$$
This is the result $E(t)$ that you where looking for.

You suppose that $\frac{dE}{dt}+E(t)=P(t)$. What make you thing that this supposition is correct ? If you want to check it put the above exact results into it and see if the equality holds. I guess this is not true in the general case.